# Jquery "Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute" error

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

I'm trying to use the [AudioPlayer.js](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/04/responsive-touch-friendly-audio-player/) jquery plugin within my custom wordpress theme. Before trying to use this within Wordpress, it was working perfect in my basic html/css test site, with no errors.

Now that it's within my WP theme, I'm getting this error when looking in Chrome Dev Tools:

```
Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'end' on 'TimeRanges':
  The index provided (0) is not less than the object's length (0).
```

And it's continuously trying to run, and Chrome keeps counting how many times it's trying to: I'm up to 22,000 attempts and counting as I type this. It also says it's because of line 103 within the Audioplayer.js file. Line 103 is:

```
barLoaded.width( ( theAudio.buffered.end( 0 ) / theAudio.duration ) * 100 + '%' );
```

I know that probably won't mean much without the whole plugin, so I've uploaded the full plugin [here on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/G2YjyaJy). I know it's not ideal to link to outside sites when asking questions, but I didn't want to post that much code here. Here's a screenshot of the error in Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]

I've made sure that Jquery is being called in the head, before the plugin is called in the footer using this code:

```
<script>jQuery( function() { jQuery( 'audio' ).audioPlayer(); } );</script>
```

Can anyone give me some ideas on what might be causing this?  Thanks!

Comment: The audioplayer.js code should really be checking that theAudio.buffered.length >= 1 before trying to get the first item of the collection (0). But it is strange that it doesn't stop throwing this error. Does the audio play correctly from the site if you put it in a simple <audio> element?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Tim! The path to the audio source wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Well I certainly don't understand the error it was throwing, but thanks to @TimHayes reply I did try just a simple HTML5 audio tag, and it still didn't play. Then I thought to use direct, explicit URL paths to assets. (Remember this is in a Wordpress theme) Now everything works! Odd. If anyone else happens to come along and has an idea why that sort of error was happening, I'd be happy to hear it!

Comment: I thought as much in my comment above. If the audio source is invalid, the content can't be buffered and audio.buffered.length will remain 0.  The audioplayer.js code doesn't account for this. So when it checks buffered.end(0) it throws an error. You should submit this bug to the developer. See the html5 spec for details about TimeRanges: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#timeranges